# how to edit initramfs to add a new partition after boot in CentOs

Tags: linux, shell, linux-kernel, centos, partitioning

I want to add a new ext3 partition by editing existed scripts or adding new scripts in initramfs in boot folder of installed CentOs. and then by replacing the new initramfs image to other installed centos and just by a reboot, a new partition ( and its file system) appear in new CentOs.

my problem is that , i don't know which script in initramfs i should change, or which new shell script i should write there? with which command and how? for example should i use fdisk command? i try but not success..

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: hmm, initramfs doesn't have that much to do with partitions, syslinux/grub resides in a boot sector, gets loaded, and they fetch a list of boot entries, Eg. linux kernel 3.11, win 7, etc. Each of those lines loads a kernel file, and for linux its initramfs file if it has one. When you say partition, do you mean boot option? a partitions would be an extent of your hard drive where you keep the boot files, or system files etc. But these have noting to do with initramfs as far as I know, and need to be created using fdisk etc. Or are you talking about the partition inside the initramfs?

Answer (score 2):

I'm gonna go on a guess here.

If I understand what you want to do correctly, what you want to do is to make another ext3 partition visible in CentOS.

If so, you want to make sure that the partition exists. Maybe you have a disk called `/dev/sda` it might have 2 partitions:

```
     sda1 ext3 mounted at /boot
and  sda2 ext3 mounted at /
```

To view this use `sudo blkid`, `fdisk-l` or similar. These partitions are loaded at boot from the list found in `/etc/fstab`.

Say you still have space left on the disk. Use fdisk/gparted to create a new ext3 partition sda3. Add a line for that disk in /etc/fstab.

Now it should be accessible after a reboot or after `sudo mount -a`.

I might have completely misunderstood your question.

### Edit #1

I think I understand what you want to do now, and you probably want to edit the `/etc/fstab` *within* the initramfs. I have never tried doing this and I don't know if it would work, but it should. In any event, unless you *really* need to mount the partitions in initramfs, use the above to mount it in fstab.

Extracting the contents of and repacking an edited initramfs is rather complex, but here are some links explaining how to extract and repack, they are for gentoo but there should be no difference:

- http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-429263-highlight-initramfs.html
- http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-383198-highlight-cpio.html
- http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-388539-highlight-.html

If you read those threads you should be able to use a script or C program to extract the contents of the initramfs, change the contents of `/etc/fstab` within initrams, and extract it back together. If you need to do this for different computers they will need to need the same contents in initramfs, or you need to do this for each computer setup.

Comment: At first I thank you very much for your good answer. In the Edited part of your answer you understood my question well, In fact I want to have an initramfs image file that perform all necessity activities to add a new partition on system boot. as you mentioned fstab should be edited, fdisk or cfdisk or.. to partitioning disk should be used, and so on.. and at the end we should mount new partition to a system file and reboot. my problem is that I do not know how to do this and run these script within initramfs. for example in which folder of initramfs I should place my scripts? thank you again.

Comment: hmm, I'm not sure where to put the scripts, but I don't understand why you specifically want to do this from initramfs? what exactly(or loosely is fine too) is it you're trying to do? unless you want to do this every time I cant see why you would gain something from doing this in an initramfs.. do you want an "installer" that resides only in initramfs? I mean, the same thing would happen every time that initramfs is used to boot, and could result in some nasty problems..

Comment: also I'm not sure fdisk etc. is available in a regular initrams, you might need to add a lot of things to your initramfs for this to work.

Comment: the necessity of doing this within "initramfs" it is that we should do all partition's changes and mount them before the disk be in used by kernel, users, programs.. ( if the disk's partitions be in used, we are not allowed to change them due to missing some data) and also a reboot is necessary after all primary changes, but within "initramfs" and because it applies changes at system boot and before any program or user's functions get the disk all changes happen, and system start with new partitions without any more reboot. am I right my friend ?!

Comment: Do you need to do this to several computers? Do you want to deploy a new linux system in one reboot on several systems? you still have to put the new initramfs on all machines.. or do you want this for automating future system changes? I feel like there should be a more straightforward way of doing whatever it is you want in a more regular way.. you could have another linux system that does this only on another partition etc. In any event, even if you do not require a reboot if you would set up the system if you make a specialized installer which is what you described, booting would be slow..

Comment: what I meant in the previous post also is that it's possible that it will be very hard to squeeze in what you need to make all those changes into an initramfs, I am no expert though.

Comment: Ok, yeah I want to run it in many servers, Thank you again for all your efforts and spending time on my question, I find a friend who seems to be able to do it. I will announce you about it in near future days.